# How to merge to kotlin coroutines together?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I have 2 flows that i would like to merge like i used to do it in RxJava.

In Rx-Java:

```
Flowable.just(1).mergeWith(Flowable.just(2)).subscribe({ println(it)}) // result: 1, 2
```

How to replicate that in Kotlin Coroutines ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flattenMerge` should provide same behaviour.  For example,

```
    val flow1 = (1..3).asFlow()
    val flow2 = (4..6).asFlow()
    flowOf(flow1, flow2).flattenMerge().collect { value ->
        println("$value")
    }
```